# Use <xs:all> in XML schema's complexType?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, complextype

I have the following XML `complexType`s defined:

```
<xs:complexType name="loss">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="lossCause" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="lossDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        <xs:element name="lossDescription" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="lossLocation" type="address" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="lossTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="officials" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="official" type="official" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:all>
    <xs:attribute name="incidentOnly" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="lawsuit" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

and:

```
<xs:complexType name="propLoss">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="loss">
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="damageDescription" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="property" type="property"/>
                <xs:element name="responsibleParty" type="contact" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:all>
            <xs:attribute name="businessOperational" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="propertyLivable" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="weatherRelated" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

However, upon validation, I get an error stating that the `all` model group isn't allowed within the `loss` `complexType` nor its extension `propLoss` definition. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A problem with `propLoss` is that you can't extend an `all` group in XML Schema (1.0). From the spec:

> Note: This specification allows only appending, and not other kinds of
>   extensions. This decision simplifies application processing required
>   to cast instances from derived to base type. Future versions may allow
>   more kinds of extension, requiring more complex transformations to
>   effect casting.

Not sure what the problem with `loss` is unless it collateral damage from the `propLoss` error.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You wouldn't happen to have any ideas for a workaround on this?

Comment: Since 'all' group items are limited to at most one occurrence, one argument is: if order is unimportant in your data model, just choose an arbitrary order for your interchange format. That is, convert each 'all' to a 'sequence'.

Answer (score 3):

Note that in XSD 1.1 `all` groups can be extended in the way shown here, with the meaning being that all of the children mentioned in either `all`-group must be present in any order.  (That is, all-group 1 and all-group 2 get merged together into a single all-group with the concatenation of their children.)